# Questions Answered by "Word of God"

Tags: discussion

There are some very detailed, well thought out, and researched answers on this site. However, many answers are conjecture. That is not usually the fault of the person answering the question, due to the lack of information available.

In a perfect world, there would always be some way to authoritatively answer any valid question. This is just simply not possible since many of these authors are long dead, and there is no other source. Think about how many questions would have amazing answers of Tolkien, Heinlein, etc. were still living.

Getting back to reality, there are still some living authors that could lend a hand such as G.R.R.M., and J.K. Rowling, and many others. But, I am not aware of any answers that they have posted themselves.

I have only been able to find one question which was answered by an authority on the subject. The question below was answered by Danny Rubin, who was the screenwriter for Groundhog Day. Are there other questions on the site which were answered by the writer or other authority?

[How long was Bill Murray's character (Phil Davis) supposed to be in a time loop in the film "Groundhog Day"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6334/35012)

Comment: Related, maybe dupe? http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2474/3567

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - Oh, there have been [more than that](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2476/20774)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming we focus purely on questions answered by word-of-god authorities where that question was ***prompted by a question asked on SFF:SE***, then there are plenty to choose from.

For example...

> [Do I need to read City of the Damned before Kinslayer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83282/do-i-need-to-read-city-of-the-damned-before-kinslayer/96754#96754)
>   - **David Guymer**
>
> [Whose buttocks are these?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66076/whose-buttocks-are-these/81161#81161) - **Charles Stross**
>
> [Why doesn't GLOPP mutate humans?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32835/why-doesnt-glopp-mutate-humans/71499#71499) - **George Broussard**
>
> [Is there an official plot explanation for the movie U.F.O. (2012)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80340/is-there-an-official-plot-explanation-for-the-movie-u-f-o-2012/81671#81671) - **Dominic Burns**
>
> [Is Dharia a matriarchy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94663/is-dharia-a-matriarchy) - **Susan Kaye Quinn**
>
> [Why is Paris flooded in Edge Of Tomorrow?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92296/why-is-paris-flooded-in-edge-of-tomorrow) - **Chris McQuarrie**
>
> [How does Shrek's rescue party reach him so fast at the end of Shrek 2?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73133/how-does-shreks-rescue-party-reach-him-so-fast-at-the-end-of-shrek-2/73138#73138)
>   - **David N. Weiss**
>
> [What has happened to books from world of "Paranoia" published by "Ultraviolet books"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102004/what-has-happened-to-books-from-world-of-paranoia-published-by-ultraviolet-bo/102478#102478)
>   - **Alan Varney**
>
> [Was "Star Wars: The Force Awakens - A Junior Novel" based on the film's script or the official novelisation?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113602/was-star-wars-the-force-awakens-a-junior-novel-based-on-the-films-script-o/113611#113611)
>   - **Michael Kogge**
>
> [Is there a heaven in the Top Cow Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8180/is-there-a-heaven-in-the-top-cow-universe/90581#90581)
>   - **Ron Marz**
>
> [Is there a reason this human character's name sounds Tymbrimi?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70575/is-there-a-reason-this-human-characters-name-sounds-tymbrimi/89677#89677) - **John Henry**
>
> [Any plans to make a movie of one of Jack Vance's books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73024/any-plans-to-make-a-movie-of-one-of-jack-vances-books/73025#73025)
>   - **John Vance**
>
> [Is there any news about the Lost Fleet books and spinoffs?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94288/is-there-any-news-about-the-lost-fleet-books-and-spinoffs/106400#106400)
>   - **John Henry**
>
> [In The Clone Wars movie, why can't Anakin understand Huttese?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64154/in-the-clone-wars-movie-why-cant-anakin-understand-huttese/71054#71054)
>   - **Karen Traviss**

Comment: There's also Eliezer Yudkowsky (sp?)'s answer to a HP:MOR question.

Answer (score 0):

[Richard's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/71054/30726) to my [In The Clone Wars movie, why can't Anakin understand Huttese?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64154/30726) question incorporates a picture of a tweet by one of the writers/producers.